# How could human-like intelligence evolve in a nonsocial, non-carnivorous species?

Tags: biology, evolution, aliens, species

It seems like two potential motivations behind human ancestors' evolution of intelligence were their complex social groups and behaviors, and hunting behavior requiring more strategic thinking in carnivorous. How could human-like intelligence evolve in a species that is herbivorous (or omnivorous leaning mostly to herbivorous)? How could human-like intelligence evolve in a solitary species, and would their social behaviors change during that process of evolution?

Comment: This one falls foul of the "_answer would need to be book-length_" check, I think. Also, we don't have a good idea of how intelligence evolves in any species, or even a particularly good idea of what intelligence _is_.

Comment: This might be very tricky, because the only type of solitary creature I'm aware of that is regarded as highly intelligent to the point of potential sapience are octopuses, and their diet is centered around anything but greens. The creature doesn't need to worry about its food running away, it doesn't need any major brains for living in a group and if it's big/strong enough it might not even need to be smart to avoid predators as adults (see some sauropods). Remember that our brains are VERY costly to maintain, so you'd need some strong pressures towards intelligence for it to evolve.

Comment: Is there an example of a non-social herbivore you're thinking of? I can't imagine how they would survive predators long enough to evolve to human-like intelligence levels. Not only that, to what extent do you mean by non-social? Achieve high intelligence but never develop a civilization?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - are they meant to stay non-social as they evolve intelligence, or is this about taking a non-social species and evolving social and intelligent behaviour? "human-like intelligence" is, fundamentally, a very social thing.

Comment: In retrospect I probably should have said human-LEVEL rather than human-like, but they don't necessarily have to remain non-social; I was more just thinking of what the descendants of a species evolving from very solitary animals could be like in terms of social behavior.

Comment: @inkwell87 They would develop a highly individualistic culture, basically how the rest of the world sees Americans (might be difficult for Americans who haven't been abroad to understand this), and they will all be libertarians. I'm only half-joking. Tigers are a good example where cubs leave very early on and once in the wild, family bonds are no longer recognized and they will attack each other defending their territory. Americans are a little like that in they move out at 18 (few other cultures do this) and define family unit to not include the grandparents.

Answer (score 4):

**Smart Enough to not be Eaten.**

The SmartyPantsSaurus evolved on a planet with humans. Humans are very intelligent and can coordinate to hunt things much bigger and stronger than them, like Bison and Wooly Mammoths.

The SmartyPantsSaurus is big and strong because it eats grass, which grows in abundance. Unlike the Wooly Mammoth it has an extra trick up its sleeve -- to outwit the hunters it evolved to be as smart as them.

Human-like intelligence in a large body is a good tradeoff, because to make something smart as a human you just have to add an extra 2lbs of brain matter, rather than say doubling the existing brain size. So for example a guinea pig with human smarts cannot eat enough to power its brain. But a blue whale just has to eat 10% more. Or eat the same amount but have 89% the bodymass.

Comment: actually brain size scales, so they don't need 2lbs more brain tissue, they need 2 times the ratio of the animals mass to human body mass.

Comment: @John That doesn't make sense to me. That would mean a human has two times as much brain mass as itself.

Comment: check your math the ration for humans is 1, so they need 2 lbs. of brain mass to do the same thing as 2lbs of human brain mass.

Answer (score 3):

**Agriculture**

It's a stretch, but solitary herbivores could develop progressively more complex grazing strategies that eventually evolve into something resembling farming. They develop a human-like intelligence because they are pressured to understand complex concepts like irrigation, crop rotation, planning harvests to avoid famine, etc.

The trick here is that social transmission of knowledge (i.e. culture) is a huge part of human intelligence. Even if they evolve human-level intelligence, if they remain solitary then their intelligence would never be human-like, and an intelligence that evolved specifically to solve tricky puzzles would be deeply alien to us. One way to develop social behaviour would be that as they grow smarter, their grazing grounds can be larger - eventually, they overlap. Then the animals start to learn cooperation, initially without communication or contact. They see what the other guy is doing, and figure out what they can do with it for mutual benefit. They would evolve to behave very predictively and communicate very little. They would, compared to humans, be better at reverse engineering (how did they get their wheat to grow in rows like this?) and worse at learning by watching and imitation.

It should go without saying that there is not evidence that this has happened, so there is probably a good reason why it doesn't work like that. But it's narratively workable.

Comment: The problem is the OP didn't define "human-like" intelligence. Does that include scientific achievements? Does non-social mean they never form a civilization? Because that would be impossible. Such a creature would at best every few thousand years birth their own Archimedes, except he doesn't socialize so his knowledge/tech isn't shared. His work might be inherited by his offspring for a couple generations then lost because they were unable to understand/replicate his work. It would inevitably remain very primitive stuck at early agriculture tech busy fending off everyday predators.

Comment: agriculture does not necessarily aid intelligence, ants practice agriculture.

Answer (score 3):

### How smart are your plants ?

**Suppose you have a mix of toxic and non-toxic plants with all kinds of fancy colors**

Antisocial, non-communicating herbivores *could* develop talent for analytical intelligence, that is connecting rationally what is received with the senses. For instance, being able to interpret plant colors as toxic or non-toxic is regarded "intelligent" behaviour for animals. If the differences would be very subtle, or *color patterns* would be involved (intelligent plant life ?) or origami leaves, or complex nut shells, the herbivore would have an incentive to develop the the brain for it. These skills could even enable the creature to pass a human IQ test with similar riddles, involving color, patterns or folding.

Your animal (?) getting used to observe plants very closely, could gain more insights about plant life, become aware of the seasonal rhythm of plants and develop tool production, *smart* agriculture etc

but..

**Suppose you always have summer and the grass is always green**

There is abundance, everything is safe to eat. Your isolated herbivores will condition themselves to graze, which does not require any intelligence. You just graze and look at the grass. When solitary, such a creature could derive some intelligence from becoming a prey animal (see Daron), but it has little stimuli in life. The brains do *not need* to train for analytical intelligence.

Answer (score 3):

Really short answer: Orangutans. They are [solitary but social](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangutan#Social_life), mature slowely and spend years with their mothers and siblings learning to use tools and build nests. But they do not really live in groups and they eat mostly fruit and leaves.
Yet they are among the smartest of apes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not

An herbivore could possibly for intelligence. Given ideal conditions and plenty of time to develop, an herbivore could overcome the advantages humans had in being omnivore. As they develop better food gathering practices, they can develop higher level of intelligence. However, this may be difficult with climate change. Animals focusing on narrow food options (strictly herbivores or carnivores) tend to suffer more than opportunistic eaters (such as omnivores) when weather conditions change.

Non-social creatures, not so much. Social creature share the burden of survival. They can share resources, provide protection to one another, give warning of danger and more importantly, share knowledge and experience. Herds of elephants rely on their elders to find the local watering holes, best places to eat and locations of danger. A solo lion male has to reinvent the wheel on its own.
Without a social structure, knowledge is not shared and passed on to the next generation and thus nothing would be improved upon and advancements tend to get lost.
Plus mating is more based on luck of the draw and has less to do with selecting the best in a large group of potential mates.

To sum it all up, vast majority of species roaming around the world we consider intelligent are omnivores (with few exceptions, elephants are herbivores and dolphins are carnivores) and almost all (I could be wrong, but I think its actually all) are social.

Answer (score -3):

Dumb predators, accidental intelligence.

Humans are **not** natural predators. We have no claws, we have no fangs, we have very little strength compared to other predators our size, we don't have super eyesight like an eagle, we don't have super noses like a dog, we don't have any venom like a snake or spider, we don't have super hearing like many predators. We are pathetic.

Although social interaction may have created some evolutionary pressure for intelligence, we developed hunting strategies **after** we became intelligent, they did not **drive** our intelligence. We had to be intelligent **first** to invent weapons, a naked animalistic human without any weapons is going to get killed even trying to tackle a wolf. And kill it, how? Trying to choke it while it rips my throat out?

Even with evolutionary pressures, intelligence is still just rare but crucial accidental mutations. There is a good plausible reason there are no other technological species, including amongst the thousands of other social species: The mutations required for intelligence are so unlikely that they occur once in a billion species.

There is no compelling reason those same mutations could not have developed in a herbivore, making them more clever than their predators.

The one mutation that seems to drive intelligence, that humans have and no other animal seems to have, including other apes, is unlimited foresight and hindsight.

This has nothing to do with hands or opposable thumbs, and not much to do with being social (so are hundreds of other species including most forms of ape), or with being hunters (many social species are foragers, not hunters).

What we can do that other animals cannot do is relate causes and effects across large stretches of time. Most animals can't manage days, we can follow cause and effect over centuries. Not only in the sense of past events causing current events (hindsight), but in the sense of successfully planning for the future (foresight).

The first farmers were, in fact, hunter gatherers, and they noticed that where they had spat or crapped seeds of melons and plants they had eaten, the same plants grew again, a year later. We have evidence that hunter gatherers on year long migration circuits intentionally carried and planted seeds along their circuit to feed themselves in the next year. (They also planted inedible flowers far from their natural origin; nobody knows why; maybe they just liked the way they looked.)

They were farmers without farms. Herders without pens, they just led goats with them and let them feed, perhaps for milk or meat when the time came.

My point is, that accidental mutation that allows unlimited cause and effect could occur in any brained animal, including a non-social herbivore.

So imagine what they would do with that intelligence. Protect themselves from predators, to start. Perhaps  even intentionally trap and kill predators, luring them into pit traps.

Perhaps they *become* limited social animals, cooperating for intelligent purposes, like farming and storing food for the winter. Even non-social herbivores have to mate and raise young, there would be evolutionary pressure to use their intelligence to ensure both happen successfully.

Perhaps they master fire.

We did not start out as either carnivores or intelligent. We suck at both, naked in the wild without intelligence.

Just like your herbivores.

My advice is to stop thinking of Intelligence as something that is the result of evolutionary pressures; it is not.

Think of it as a rare combination of mutations that happens entirely by chance to some animal, **any** animal, and then evolutionary pressures act on it and shape it.

So first pick your animal that wins this lottery (as we did), and **then** project the rational future of that animal once it has more intelligence than any other animal.

Comment: The common ancestor of the African great apes, including humans, was an African great ape. It was quite intelligent (all apes are intelligent) and it lived in social groups (all African great apes live in social groups). They never had to face a predator *alone*. There is strength in numbers. Moreover, humans absolutely are predators, and were predators from day one. We are not "pathetic", we are adapted for endurance. Endurance is our evolutionary advantage as pure animals; yes, a cheetah can easily outrun a human over 100 meters, but the human can easily outrun the cheetah over a kilometer.

Comment: Correction: we have fangs. They're just not very long.

Comment: "stop thinking of Intelligence as something that is the result of evolutionary pressures; it is not." is an objectively wrong statement. Nearly every single trait that goes on to be an integral part of a species is related to 2 things: the mutations that eventually cause that trait to exist and the natural selection that deems it helpful or at least not a hindrance to the thing's survival. Being intelligent isn't just a random 100% beneficial thing for every creature, it takes a lot of energy to maintain, and if the extra brains can't "pull their weight" properly, they become a hindrance.

Comment: If you want a simple example of how intelligence can be a problem without even minding metabolic cost: if you leave a koala in a room which basically mimics its habitat and gives it food everyday without trying to give it anything else new to occupy itself with for a prolonged time, it'll likely be fine. If you do the same thing with an octopus, it can and likely will become "bored" and stressed, and might respond to such stress by cannibalizing itself, leaving it open to infections and potentially resulting in its death.

Comment: @ProjectApex We'll disagree. Evolutionary pressure never creates a mutation. Random copy error creates mutations. Evolutionary pressure **retains** or **discards** mutations. That is it. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands of species that could benefit from, and sustain, higher intelligence. So why aren't they highly intelligent? The evolutionary pressure for high intelligence does not in any way ensure the necessary **mutations** for high intelligence will occur! To claim otherwise is anti-scientific magical thinking.

Comment: @AlexP Then why aren't **all** the apes pursuit predators? Many of them eat meat. Why did only the ancestors of humans become pursuit predators, and adapt for endurance? The answer is simple, we were smart and realized pursuit predation was possible **before** we became pursuit predators. We ran because we knew what would happen if we pursued an animal for hours on end. It would collapse.  We retained our sweat glands and low fur density because of **other** evolutionary pressures, and were able to take up pursuit when we evolved time-unlimited cause/effect correlations.

Comment: I don't remember saying the pressures for a certain trait are what **cause** it to appear. That's lamarck's wrong theory of evolution. I said that Natural selection, to put it simply, "tells what stays and what goes". It's the second, equally important part of the process. Just like you said: if the necessary genes for something aren't ever there, they cannot be selected, but if natural selection is acting against those genes, they will not be kept either. Higher Intelligence can be beneficial, but human-level intelligence isn't necessarily beneficial for everything on earth.

Comment: I mean, look at dragonflies as a whole for a simple example. They're certainly not the smartest creatures around (through I'd dare say I'm not sure if they couldn't outsmart a koala in some situations), nor are they apex predators, yet they're undoubtedly among the most successful, having been around for millions of years and being the most effective predators in the entire world as far as we're aware, with a body plan so good and efficient for its lifestyle that we study it for making our drones to this day.

Comment: @ProjectApex I don't understand your point. We are pursuit predators because we developed intelligence; not the other way around. Other animals don't have our attention span; most predators don't think more than a few minutes ahead. Apes seem incapable of learning to take actions that will pay off hours later, no matter how we try to teach them. To be a pursuit predator, we needed both the intelligence to know it would work, to make spears and knives to finish the animal off, to cook it, etc. It was a lifestyle born of getting smart, we did not get smart **because** we were pursuit predators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132882/discussion-between-projectapex-and-amadeus).

Comment: *"Why aren't all the apes pursuit predators":* for the same reason that not all descendants of the first bony fishes crawled onto land.  *Some* fishes adapted to live on land. They were not perfectly adapted from the beginning; just like immediately after the split humans were not perfectly adapted to run and walk long distances. *All* apes can walk on two legs, and they do so if needed; *our* ancestors had fewer trees in their environment, and the environment favored walking upright. Endurance, long attention span and intelligence *co-evolved* over some two million years.

Comment: chimps hunt, so it is likely out common ancestor also hunted, so hunting predates high intelligence in hominids. chimps even use spears in hunting. if anything caused intelligence in humans it was the advent of cooking which doubled our caloric intake. pursuit predations could have happened before or after rapid inflation of the brain. All the anatomical prerequisites predate it by a wide margin. intelligence is very obviously a result of evolutionary selection, we a step wise advancement in hominid evolution.

Comment: @John Yet another misunderstanding of evolution. Environment does not invent anything or cause anything. Give a thousand generations of monkeys twice the calories, and that isn't going to make them any smarter, just less hungry, and perhaps fatter and less fit. If anything, the intelligence happened first, and the cooking "idea" was realized and invented as a result of the greater caloric needs created by the intelligence mutation.

Comment: @Amadeus first  cooking evolved first so your idea holds no water, second drastically lowering the negative constraints on a feature (relative caloric cost for brain size)  will increase the selective fitness of the feature. Evolution is not the same thing as just mutation and all evolution happens with the constraints of selective pressures. Perhaps you don't understand evolution as well as you think you do.

Comment: @John You are claiming something you cannot possibly know. And it doesn't make a difference if you lower the cost of a feature, that does not increase the likelihood of a mutation for that feature. It would cost whales less calories to mutate away their vestigial leg bones, but they never have. And several species have larger brains that humans without human intelligence, Corvids have small brains and are more intelligent than dogs, and you cannot explain why, if human intelligence is so valuable, why it has occurred in only one of tens of millions of species. It was just a random mutation.

Comment: @Amadeus the most likely reason it has only occurred in humans is while highly valuable it is also EXTREMEMLY costly, our brains consume a third of the calories we eat, that is a massive cost, more than pregnancy. the likelyhood of a mutation is NOT the likelihood a feature evolving, a mutation is only the lower bounds, it is not one mutation creating human brains but a series of mutations, mutations are extremely common so a feature that can occur will likely occur multiple times but it needs to occur in the right selective environment to matter.

Comment: @John Nobody knows what gene or genes causes high human intelligence, so you don't know if it was one gene or many. And simple logic should tell you that if it is so wildly useful for humans, despite being extremely costly, then it would be the same for any other animal; and therefore prevalent. But it is not. You have not provided a plausible explanation for why we are a singular species an order of magnitude brighter than the next closest intelligent species; including those like apes that have brains of nearly the same size. The correct answer is a wildly improbable mutation.

Comment: @Amadeus I don't need ot know what gene causes an adaptation to know what selective pressures effect it. and you seem to be overestimating how beneficial intelligence is, for most of our species history it was not particularly powerful, not until we had the chance to build thousands of generations of collected knowledge. we are not orders of magnitude smarter than our nearest relative, we are orders of magnitude smarter than our nearest living relative which is a very different thing. Also other living apes do not have a brain nearly the same size as ours.

Comment: @Amadeus our brains are 3 times the size of a chimp brain even accounting to body mass, yet there is very little our brain can do that a chimps cannot, it is a difference of amount not ability, chimps even preform better in some tasks like memory. I suggest you familiarize your self with evolution of hominids. you will see how our evolution follows a fairly obvious pattern, mot of our unique features evolve before our large brain and increasing intelligence follows multiple paths with our line simply being the one that won.

Comment: One last thing I forgot to mention at our discussion: komodo Dragons are also not the smartest, nor do they have the greatest attention span, yet they too play the role of persistence* predator (same as us) in their natural habitat. They can track prey and find carrion through smell, and they know that a bitten prey will inevitably die, so they just need to give the first bite and play the long game, made a little shorter because the prey is both getting tired and dying due to a mix of nasty venom and bacterial infections. High intelligence isn't necessary for persistence predation.